# react-select and @typeform/embed

Tags: embed, react-select, typeform

In a vanilla create-react-app adding react-select and @typeform/embed as dependencies and then importing both results in Webpack failing to compile with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'border-radius:0;display:block;height:2px;width:25px;position:absolute;right:6px;top:6px;' of undefined

This is caused by having both 
`import Select from "react-select"` and 
`import { ReactTypeformEmbed } from "react-typeform-embed"` in files to be compiled

The problem seems to be with the Typeform Embed SDK as shown in this screenshot [Typeform SDK issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5ng2.png)

Has anyone come across this/had this problem? The Tyepform import seems to work as soon as I remove the React Select import.

Comment: Hi Riccardo,

are you aware of the React wrapper for the Typeform SDK?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-typeform-embed

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Guys any update on the solution ? as I am facing the same issue

Comment: @NicolasGrenié indeed I am using react-typeform-embed, however @typeform/embed is a transitive dependency that gets dropped in by said library hence the conflict